# React native You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

when I run the command on cmd "react-native run-android" it says -
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
> [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
> Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

-I did the following and give me a same error?

"C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin"
Open cmd
Type
sdkmanager.bat licenses
Accept all licenses with 'y'
Accepted

I am getting error one after one again n again. who the dumb developed this system

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to open the android studio SDK tools and update the recent version. I also followed the way u did, it didn't work for me. I had to install the latest versions to run it :)

Comment: I have latest version 27.0.1 updated including 26.0.2 and 24.0.0 and 23.0.1 but not working. please can u help me anyway

Answer (score 0):

you need to download and accept license Build-Tools 23.0.1 by doing following things

```
Android\sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager.bat "build-tools;23.0.1"
```